# Sci fi movie or short in which an octopus is captured put in a tank but uses ink to hide

Tags: story-identification, movie

Sci fi movie in which an octopus is captured put in a tank but uses ink to hide.  It escapes and uses camouflage. DNA is involved, making it smarter.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?  Who captured it?

Comment: It would help to know what language it was in too. Please enjoy our [tour] and refer to the [help] as and when you need guidance as to our ways. There's also a [meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), also [handy checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2041/105884) regarding story id questions that might be helpful to you. Welcome to Scifi.

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1619880/?

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible this is the episode "[8](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11839578/)" of [*The Twilight Zone*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2583620/) (2019)?

The [plot summary on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twilight_Zone_(2019_TV_series)#Season_2_(2020)) says:

> A team of scientists are taking part in a program investigating the depletion of ice shelves, as well as the search for new Antarctic species. Two members of the team, Kasper and Doug, are on a dive. One of the divers, Doug, resurfaces from the water, fighting off an unknown being, which ultimately wins the battle. Doug and another scientist trying to help, Amy, are pulled into the water and blood sprays out all across the room. The remaining five scientists discover the bloody water and room, as well as **a large octopus, which has hidden itself in a cooler** near the diving hole. Ling, a woman sent as an observer from the Chinese Antarctic Administration, insists that the octopus be saved and taken to the lab for observation. Meanwhile, one of the scientists, Frisch, dives into the water, with the hopes of discovering what happened to his team members. Frisch quickly resurfaces with one of the missing divers, Kasper, who is dead. The group all believe the octopus in their lab is responsible for the deaths of Amy, Kasper, and Doug. Ling again insists that the octopus must be kept alive and well. Through a translating device and Channing’s phone, Ling is able to eavesdrop and hear two of the scientists, Channing and Orson, discuss their mission to find the species and deliver it to a doctor. The doctor believes that chemicals extracted from the octopus can be used for pain management. At this time, **the octopus escapes the tank it was placed in**, then uses its tentacles to kill Larry and Frisch. In the process, one of the octopus’ tentacles is cut off. Channing discovers the dead bodies, as well as the chopped off tentacle of the missing octopus. Channing also finds her phone in Ling’s room, and explains to Orson that Ling had heard their discussion about their real intentions for the octopus. The octopus gains access to the phone and, through it, the data that Ling has collected on the species, which is displayed on the projector in front of Orson, Channing, and Ling. It is discovered that Ling has also been in search of this species, in order to investigate the physical mechanisms of the octopus, hoping to use the data to “change what a human being can be” via gene editing. Orson argues that they both wanted to exploit the animal for humanity’s benefit, which is wrong, and that they should release the octopus back into its environment. Meanwhile, Channing is tracking the octopus’ movements in the ducts, and ultimately is attacked by the creature. The octopus eventually releases Channing and her phone, then escapes through the ducts to the ocean. Through the projector, the scientists see **the octopus has manipulated the sequence of gene mutation**, allowing it to develop the ability to evolve, ultimately allowing this creature, and other ocean life, to take over life on land and put an end to the human species.